# Struts 2 Autocompleter tag

Tags: java, struts2, autocomplete

I use struts 2 Autocompleter for my web application, but it limit only 30 option list which return from my ajax method. I want to use **resultsLimit** to change the limitation and it doesn't work at all.

here is my struts tag for Autocompleter:

```
<s:autocompleter theme="qajax" id="payerBox" name="payerProfileName" 
                keyName="selectPayerCatProfileTypeId"                       
                formId="confirm" autoComplete="false" forceValidOption="true"
                listenTopics="/payerCategoryTypeChanged" 
                required="true" href="%{#loadPayerCategory}" resultsLimit="-1" >                    
</s:autocompleter>
```

Please help guiding me with this.

Comment: Where did you find that `resultsLimit` attribute?

Comment: I use struts2-core-2.0.8, and it also describe in the documentation here: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/autocompleter.html

Comment: Why do you use such an old version? Can you upgrade?

Comment: @HangSoungChann you should REALLY upgrade to a version newer than 2.3.16, due to security issues, and thousands of bugfixes... and start using struts2-jquery-plugin